# Firebase custom application setup

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-storage

```
customApp= new FirebaseApp(getApplicationContext(),"My News",<to be filled>);
    storage = FirebaseStorage.getInstance(customApp);
```

I'm new to firebase and what is the exact use of the custom App.

I want to create a custom app to upload large files to google cloud storage using firebase. is that custom app recommended for me?

Answer (score 1):

No need to use customApp;

Simply we can use

```
storage = FirebaseStorage.getInstance("gs://<Google cloud storage bucket name>");
```

If we want storage references then

```
mStorageRef = storage.getReferenceFromUrl("gs://<Google cloud storage bucket name>");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  @Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    FirebaseOptions options = new FirebaseOptions.Builder()
            .setApiKey("AI...3LnY")
            .setStorageBucket("gs://f...t")
            .setApplicationId("1:356....:android:f......232")
            .build();
    customApp = FirebaseApp.initializeApp(getApplicationContext(),options,"MyApp");
    //storage
    storage = FirebaseStorage.getInstance(customApp);`enter code here`
```

}

Comment: we can use firebase customApp that illustrated in above code

Answer (score 0):

If you're new to Firebase, chances are you don't need a custom `FirebaseApp`. Instead, just use `FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference()` as shown in the [Firebase Storage documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/android/create-reference).

Answer (score 0):

Great answer Mr. Frank van Puffelen.
It's working for me (imported bucket from Google Cloud Storage.)

```
mStorageRef = FirebaseStorage.getInstance("gs://c......s").getReference();
```

Download the file from google cloud storage to a local device using firebase.

```
final StorageReference downloadRef;
        downloadRef = mStorageRef.getRoot().child(downloadPath);

        try {
            File output = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + File.separator + Config.MY_VIDEOS_PATH);
            if (!output.exists()) {
                output.mkdir();
            }
            localFile = new File(output, downloadId);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


        // Download and get total bytes
        downloadRef.getFile(localFile)
                .addOnProgressListener(new OnProgressListener<FileDownloadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onProgress(FileDownloadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                        showProgressNotification(title, "",
                                taskSnapshot.getBytesTransferred(),
                                taskSnapshot.getTotalByteCount());
                    }
                })
                .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<FileDownloadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(FileDownloadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                        Log.d(TAG, "download:SUCCESS");
                        // Send success broadcast with number of bytes downloaded
                        broadcastDownloadFinished(downloadPath, taskSnapshot.getTotalByteCount());
                        showDownloadFinishedNotification(downloadPath, (int) taskSnapshot.getTotalByteCount());

                        // Mark task completed
                        taskCompleted();
                    }
                })
                .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception exception) {
                        Log.w(TAG, "download:FAILURE", exception);
                        Log.w(TAG, "download:FAILURE", exception.getCause());

                        // Send failure broadcast
                        broadcastDownloadFinished(downloadPath, -1);
                        showDownloadFinishedNotification(downloadPath, -1);

                        // Mark task completed
                        taskCompleted();
                    }
                });
```